# Can't send data to PostgreSQL database

Tags: php, html, database, forms, postgresql

I'm trying to make an registration system where an user enters his name and his email and receives an email where he'll confirm the subscription. After this, this code can be used to enter some personal information that are requiered to checkin at a hotel room. The problem is that I can't send the data to the database, I can submit the form but the data it's not send to the database, so no email will be send to that person. Here it's the code:

```
<?php
//register.php

include('database_connection.php');

if(isset($_SESSION['user_id']))
{
    header("location:index.php");
}

$message = '';

if(isset($_POST["register"]))
{
    $query = "
    SELECT * FROM tregister
    WHERE email = :user_email
    ";
    $statement = $connect->prepare($query);
    $statement->execute(
        array(
            ':user_email'   =>  $_POST['user_email']
        )
    );
    $no_of_row = $statement->rowCount();
    if($no_of_row > 0)
    {
        $message = '<label class="text-danger">Email Already Exits</label>';
    }
    else
    {

        $user_activation_code = md5(rand());
        $user = (isset($_POST['user_name']) && !empty($_POST['user_name'])) ? $_POST['user_name'] : "" ;
        $email = (isset($_POST['user_email']) && !empty($_POST['user_email'])) ? $_POST['user_email'] : "" ;
        $insert_query = "
        INSERT INTO tregister
        (nume, email, cod_activare, email_status)
        VALUES ('$user','$email','$user_activation_code','$email_status');
        ";
        $statement = pg_prepare($connect,$insert_query);
//HERE IT'S THE PROBLEM I think
        $statement=pg_execute($connect,array(
                ':user_name'            =>  $_POST['user_name'],
                ':user_email'           =>  $_POST['user_email'],
                ':user_activation_code' =>  $user_activation_code,
                ':user_email_status'    =>  '0'
            )
        );

        $result = pg_fetch_all($statement);
        var_dump($result);
        if(isset($result))
        {
            $base_url = "http://dev.incorom.local/login-robinson/www/login.php";  //change this baseurl value as per your file path
            $mail_body = "
            <p>Hi ".$_POST['user_name'].",</p>
            <p>Thanks for Registration. </p>
            <p>Please Open this link to verified your email address - ".$base_url."email_verification.php?activation_code=".$user_activation_code."
            <p>Best Regards,<br />Webslesson</p>
            ";
            require 'class/class.phpmailer.php';
            $mail = new PHPMailer;
            $mail->IsSMTP();                                //Sets Mailer to send message using SMTP
            $mail->Host = 'smtpout.secureserver.net';       //Sets the SMTP hosts of your Email hosting, this for Godaddy
            $mail->Port = '80';                             //Sets the default SMTP server port
            $mail->SMTPAuth = true;                         //Sets SMTP authentication. Utilizes the Username and Password variables
            $mail->Username = '';                   //Sets SMTP username
            $mail->Password = '';                   //Sets SMTP password
            $mail->SMTPSecure = '';                         //Sets connection prefix. Options are "", "ssl" or "tls"
            $mail->From = 'info@webslesson.info';           //Sets the From email address for the message
            $mail->FromName = 'Webslesson';                 //Sets the From name of the message
            $mail->AddAddress($_POST['user_email'], $_POST['user_name']);       //Adds a "To" address
            $mail->WordWrap = 50;                           //Sets word wrapping on the body of the message to a given number of characters
            $mail->IsHTML(true);                            //Sets message type to HTML
            $mail->Subject = 'Email Verification';          //Sets the Subject of the message
            $mail->Body = $mail_body;                           //An HTML or plain text message body
            if($mail->Send())                               //Send an Email. Return true on success or false on error
            {
                $message = '<label class="text-success">Register Done, Please check your mail.</label>';
            }
        }
    }
}

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>PHP Register Login Script with Email Verification</title>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <br />
        <div class="container" style="width:100%; max-width:600px">
            <h2 align="center">PHP Register Login Script with Email Verification</h2>
            <br />
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading"><h4>Register</h4></div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <form method="post" id="register_form">
                        <?php echo $message; ?>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>User Name</label>
                            <input type="text" name="user_name" class="form-control" pattern="[a-zA-Z ]+" required />
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>User Email</label>
                            <input type="email" name="user_email" class="form-control" required />
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="submit" name="register" id="register" value="Register" class="btn btn-info" />
                        </div>
                    </form>
                    <p align="right"><a href="login.php">Login</a></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here it's the database_connection:

```
<?php
//database_connection.php

$connect = new PDO('pgsql:host=localhost;dbname=login_robinson', 'robinson', '1234');
session_start();

?>
```

Comment: Technically `PDOStatement::rowCount()` returns the number of rows affected by the last `INSERT`, `UPDATE` or `DELETE` query **not** the number of rows returned from a `SELECT` statement (though some DBs will do this). Try doing a count on the recordset instead.

Comment: the placeholders are missing in your insert, use :user_name , not $user

Comment: The thing is that this code it's perfectly working for mysql but for Postgres it's not working and I don't understand why..